# Filter Firebase array of items in order of Timestamp then return only the oldest item in Swiftui

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

All,  I have a list of meetings.  I am fetching this array using the following code:

```
    @MainActor
static func fetchMeeting(limit: Int? = nil) async throws -> [Meeting] {
    let snapshot = try await FirestoreConstants.MeetingsCollection.getDocuments()
    let query = FirestoreConstants.MeetingsCollection.order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
    if let limit {
        let snapshot = try await query.limit(to: limit).getDocuments()
        return mapMeeting(fromSnapshot: snapshot)
    }
    return snapshot.documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Meeting.self) })
    
}
private static func mapMeeting(fromSnapshot snapshot: QuerySnapshot) -> [Meeting] {
    return snapshot.documents
        .compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Meeting.self) })
}
```

Then in my viewModel i filter this fetch down to 1 Meeting using this code:

```
    private let fetchLimit = 1

//This will be for user Main screen display
@MainActor
func fetchMeeting() async throws {
    self.meetings1 = try await MeetingService.fetchMeeting(limit: fetchLimit)
}
```

Now this returns that 1 meeting as a 1 item array:

```
@Published var meetings1 = [Meeting]()
```

How can I turn that 1 item array into a single item "currentmeeting" so i can use its contents freely?  :

```
@Published var upcomingmeeting: Meeting?
```

thank you all!!
ja

I've made these changes..

```
class MeetingViewModel: ObservableObject{
    init(){
        Task{ try await fetchAllMeetings() }
        Task{ try await fetchMeeting()}
    }
    
    @Published var upcomingmeeting: Meeting?
    @Published var meetings1 = [Meeting]() {
        didSet {
            if let first = meetings1.first {
                upcomingmeeting = first
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: fetchMeeting() init pulls my meetings1 array.

My Model:

```
struct Meeting: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let uid: String
    let address: String
    let citystate: String
    let hostsite: String
    let title: String
    let timestamp: Timestamp
}
```

My body...

```
struct HomeAdminView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MeetingViewModel()

    var body: some View {
                    Text(viewModel.currentmeeting?.title ?? "no name")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .onAppear{
                                print("----> before upcomingmeeting: \(viewModel.upcomingmeeting)")
                                viewModel.meetings1.append(Meeting(title: "meeting-1"))
                                print("----> after upcomingmeeting: \(viewModel.upcomingmeeting)")
                            }
}
```

I am not following how the append "meeting-1" works?  i am so sorry.
i am getting this error.
[image]

This worked. on my Body/View:

```
                Text(viewModel.upcomingmeeting?.title ?? "no name")
```

i incorrectly had this...

```
                Text(viewModel.currentmeeting?.title ?? "no name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach using `didSet`, such as:

```
@Published var meetings1 = [Meeting]() {
    didSet {
        if let first = meetings1.first {
            currentmeeting = first
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

Here is my full test code that shows the approach of using `didSet` works.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = TestModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(model.upcomingmeeting?.name ?? "no name")
            .onAppear {
                print("---> before upcomingmeeting: \(model.upcomingmeeting)")
                // simulated adding to the meetings1
                model.meetings1.append(Meeting(name: "meeting-1"))
                print("---> after upcomingmeeting: \(model.upcomingmeeting)")
            }
    }
}

struct Meeting: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

class TestModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var upcomingmeeting: Meeting?
    @Published var meetings1 = [Meeting]() {
        didSet {
            if let first = meetings1.first {
                upcomingmeeting = first
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that and get a blank return.

Comment: @Published var meetings1 = [Meeting](){
        didSet{
            if let first = meetings1.first{
                upcomingmeeting = first
            }
        }
    }

Comment: i do have a init() call in that viewmodel that does fetch that array of 1 item and it does pull it because i can show that one meeting in a list of 1. well, you know bc its an array.

Comment: what is that `upcomingmeeting`, is it the same as `currentmeeting` that you show?

Comment: yes. it is.  i use current meeting elsewhere passing it after its established from a list.  had to create upcomingmeeting for this problem. i am sorry, i edited my original question to reflect.

Comment: updated my answer with my test code. Let us know if that does not work. Also show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: soooo sorry!!!!  see my last edit.  i mistakingly added wrong variable. inside my Text(). see last post.  your did set worked great!!